# Natty loves to freeze itself

Tags: 11.04, installation, freeze, system

I just upgraded my Maverick to Natty 3 days ago. It's fun and good. I try to be familiar with Unity, but the Natty constantly freezes suddenly. I try another alternative, I use Ubuntu Classic instead of Unity, and at the end my computer continues freezing suddenly and it made me really angry, I can't do anything except of force my computer to shut down through the power button. My laptop is Compaq CQ20 windows & 32bit

Comment: do you have any propietary drivers installed?

Comment: of course, I already installed the drivers through "Additional Driver" at system menu

Comment: most likely is that, are they nvidia or ati? uninstall them and keep the nouveou or radeonHD drivers a.k.a the open source one's

Comment: i only have integrated graphic card.

Comment: intel integrated graphics? 'cause there's amd too...

Comment: Do you know which WiFi chipset your laptop uses? There have been problems with Broadcom chipsets that I've seen.

Comment: First of all, try to disable compiz completely. Additionally, disable all radio modules (bluetooth, wifi, whatever). Work a little and see if problems disappear.

Comment: You had too many questions in this post. I've removed the two specific questions about Wifi and the installation failing on your other machine. Please ask those as separate questions - or search the site to see if they have been already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your repositories.

```
     deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu natty main #xorg-edgers PPA                  
    deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates natty main #xorg-edgers PPA
```

or in the terminal:

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

or Open the Software Sources menu by going to Applications->Ubuntu Software Center, then selecting Edit->Software Sources. Choose the Other Software tab and click Add.

```
     ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

and then

```
     sudo apt-get update
```

see if it helps.

Comment: You advise a supposedly non-guru user to upgrade to non-default X ? I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: it's not that hard.. clicking the  ubuntu logo, and go to software sources and add the ppa.. it's pretty straight forward?

Comment: or opening a terminal and typing the ppa to add it

Comment: and why not? the present state the drivers he's using are causing that if he updates them he's most likely to get it fixed.

Comment: Xorg-edgers is not for the faint of heart - it's populated with automated builds of upstream development.  There's no guarantee those packages will work at all.

Comment: mm, it never gave me any problem but ok... chnaged it to x-swat ppa

Answer (score 0):

Besides Uri answer try this too: enable **proposed updates** in Software Sources, and update your system to  **2.6.38-9** kernel. Maybe this helps.

Comment: thanks for your feedbacks, but I get confused of too many answers given, can you give me the straight forward answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP MINI 210 and it freezes like yours, my issue? the wireless card!

the solution:
blacklisting the following drivers:

```
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt2x00lib
```

(this should be appended to the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf)

then restart and it should be working if this is your issue!

if this doesn't work, don't forget to remove those lines from the file.

good luck!